# Celery unavailable after dockerization in a Django app

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, celery

I have a Django app that I've been trying to dockerize. I've successfully dockerized Django with gunicorn and nginx so the main part of the app is running.

However, I also have tasks that need to be run using Celery. I dockerized rabbitmq, and I think that was successful, as before installing it I had `Connexion refused` and I don't anymore.

I only lack Celery to be dockerized so, as my tasks are not executed nor stored in the database, my Celery configuration is probably wrong, however I couldn't find where I'm going wrong with it.

Here is my **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  django_gunicorn:
    volumes:
      - static:/app/static
      - media:/media
    env_file:
      - env
    build:
      context: .
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/static
      - media:/media
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - django_gunicorn

  rabbitmq3:
    image: rabbitmq:3-alpine
    ports:
      - 5672:5672

  celery:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    command: celery -A main worker -l info
    env_file:
      - env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq3
      - django_gunicorn


volumes:
  static:
  media:
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.10.5-alpine

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN wget https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/First-google-logo.gif -O media/media.gif

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./src /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh

python manage.py migrate
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

gunicorn main.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

**Celery container logs**

```
C:\Users\stephane.bernardelli\Documents\TestApp>docker logs 60b3767e9845
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, django_celery_beat, django_celery_results, scripts, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

9771 static files copied to '/app/static'.
[2022-07-22 08:32:33 +0000] [9] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-07-22 08:32:33 +0000] [9] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (9)
[2022-07-22 08:32:33 +0000] [9] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-07-22 08:32:33 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, django_celery_beat, django_celery_results, scripts, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

0 static files copied to '/app/static', 9771 unmodified.
[2022-07-22 08:55:07 +0000] [9] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-07-22 08:55:07 +0000] [9] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (9)
[2022-07-22 08:55:07 +0000] [9] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-07-22 08:55:07 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is because your containers are unable to talk to each other. By default all the containers are in bridge network and this issue arises. You can try grouping all the containers in a network as shown below.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  django_gunicorn:
    volumes:
      - static:/app/static
      - media:/media
    env_file:
      - env
    build:
      context: .
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - dev_network

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/static
      - media:/media
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - django_gunicorn
    networks:
      - dev_network

  rabbitmq3:
    image: rabbitmq:3-alpine
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
    networks:
      - dev_network

  celery:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    command: celery -A main worker -l info
    env_file:
      - env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq3
      - django_gunicorn
    networks:
      - dev_network

networks:
  dev_network:
    external: false

volumes:
  static:
  media:
```

And in your celery configuration for broker URL, you need to specify it in this format.

```
amqp://username:password@rabbitmq3:5672/
```

in your **entrypoint.sh**  add the below line at the end so that docker-compose commands also gets executed.

```
exec "$@"
```

or you can remove the Entrypoint from DockerFile and do as below.

for `gunicorn` container command in docker-compose.yml

```
command:
      [sh, -c, "python manage.py migrate && gunicorn main.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 "]
```

**Note :** collect the static file before hand or you can append it in the above command

for `celery` container command in docker-compose.yml remains same.

**Note:** using the second method is not an issue in this case. But if you have some complex validation or task to perform before container spin up, go with Entrypoint script only

Comment: I tried that but that didn't work. In my settings I have `CELERY_BROKER_URL="amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq3:5672/"` and I think that works since when I remove this line I get the `connexion refused` error. However what I remarked was that Celery doesn't seem to be starting as I don't get the Celery starting display, so I think it's not running rather than not able to communicate.

Comment: Did you add networks property as shown above ?can you share the celery container logs ? **docker logs <container id>**

Comment: I added the logs, and yes I added the networks property you suggested

Comment: Is that the celery log or gunicorn log ? The issue is entrypoint takes precedence over command. That is why your celery command in your docker-compose is not run, which you can see in logs. only the django startup command is run.

Comment: That's the Celery logs..that's what I was thinking, I'll dive into it in order to make the entrypoint not take precedence, maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72587417/celery-tasks-not-running-in-docker-compose) will be able to help me

Comment: yes correct. That is how you are supposed to do it or you can remove entrypoint and just give the commands for gunicorn in docker-compose file

Comment: I succeeded in starting Celery ! Thank you so much ! (Currently gunicorn is not working cause I just removed the entrypoint file but that shouldn't be too hard to fix). You can post it as an answer, I'll accept it since you helped me find the root of the problem !

Comment: @Balizok, Updated the answer, please check

Comment: The `networks:` changes are unnecessary; Compose creates a network named `default` and attaches all of the containers to it automatically.  I would recommend leaving a default `CMD gunicorn ...` in the Dockerfile, and _not_ write an extended shell script in the Compose file.